# How to use DisplayTag with nested Lists and Properties in Struts 2

Tags: hibernate, struts2, struts, displaytag

I'm trying to display a list. Inside this list there is another list which I want to display. With Struts my code looked like this:

```
<s:iterator value="lendingList">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="lendBy.matNumber" /> <s:property
                value="lendBy.firstName" /> <s:property value="lendBy.name" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="date" /></td>
        <td><s:iterator value="publication">
                <s:property value="isbn" />
            </s:iterator></td>
        <td><s:iterator value="publication">
                <s:property value="title" />
            </s:iterator></td>
        <td><s:property value="returnDate" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="remindProcessStarted" /></td>
```

The new DisplayTag Table looks like this:

```
<display:table id="lendingList" name="lendingList" pagesize="6"
    cellpadding="5px;" cellspacing="5px;"
    style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;" requestURI="" sort="list">
    <display:column property="lendBy.matNumber" title="Mat.-Nr."
        sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="lendBy.firstName" title="Nachname"
        sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="lendBy.name" title="Vorname" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="publication.isbn" title="Vorname" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="publication.title" title="Vorname" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="returnDate" title="Rückgabedatum"
        sortable="true" />

</display:table>
```

I tried to access the properties with `publication.isbn`, but unfortunately it is not working. I couldn't find any hints in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had to give a `uid` to the table, after that I can access the properties with a Struts `iterator` like this:

```
<display:column media="html" title="Titel" sortable="true">
    <s:iterator value="#attr.lendingList.publication">
        <s:property value="title" />
    </s:iterator>
</display:column>
```

Comment: short question but i dont want to open a new topic: can i get the size of a display:column property if the item is a list? like: display:column property="reminderSend.size() ?